# Is there a way to import record type without fields?

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to import record type without fields?

Currently the code of issue is:
`import Database.Tables (Post)` where `Post` is a record type. However I do not want the fields to be imported as well.

Comment: `import Database.Tables (Post)` doesn't import the fields or the constructors, only the type.

Comment: Why do you believe the fields have been imported as well? What are the other imports? What package provides `Database.Tables`? There are way too few details here to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`import Database.Tables (Post)` doesn't import the fields or the constructors, only the type.